# Starting the servlet contextListener but can't starts the application index.jsp(Home Page)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

my web.xml file code

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.vts.action.Server</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Server.java code....

```
public class Server extends HttpServlet implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Socket clientsocket;
    ServerSocket socket = null;
    int PORT = 9090;

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("ServletContextListener destroyed");

    }
       @Override
       public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) 
        {
           // hear code create socket server and accept multiple client connection and                        
              String via gps and save string in database is working correctly 
        }
}
```

BUT 
Now my problem is i want to accept continue string via gps run in background

But index.jsp page is not started thought that is my welcome file. I am not sure whether the listener configuration in my web.xml is right or wrong.....plz give Suggestion

Thanks & Regards

Krishnakant

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve, and what your error is. You have a servlet that acts as a listener, but the servlet itself seems to do nothing. Are you sure you even need to use a servlet container for the task you're trying to solve?

Comment: @NilsH seems he has not shared that part of the code instead he has written a comment "hear code create socket server and accept multiple client connection and String via gps and save string in database is working correctly"

Comment: Yes, inside contextInitialized. My point was that there is no get/post relevant code in the servlet.

Comment: thaks for rply nilesh i want trying when run index.jsp(Home page) then run Servlet.java class but i want run serlet.java run contiguously background...

Comment: But what is the error?

Comment: index.jsp page not open curser goes contextListner method for accept client data...!

Comment: I'm still not getting it. If you want help with this issue, you have to provide some more information and details about the error situation.

Comment: Hi nilesh, i am working on vehicle tracking system project in that i want to receive gps data contiguously using TCP and store in database hence i am use Listener in servlet,and in that method use server socket program TCP connection for accept data...!!My problem is that when i run index.jsp(HomePage) then cursor goes to Server.java class in contextInitialized method and perform datdabase operation,BUT Can not open insex.jsp page in my Browser...!!plz guid me is it correct way or not ...!! Can u send me ur mail Id i send u my code on ur mail id...!My id (krishnakantkadam@rediffmail.com)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Reply ,Finally i get Solution...
i am use threading in server side with TCP connection and create two java class MyListerner.java  in that use contextListner method

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("ServletContextListener destroyed");
}
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.submit(new RunClassOnDeployment(arg0.getServletContext()));
}
```

in contextInitialized call server.java(TCP connecton with threading)

```
vtsDataDao vtsData ;
ServletContext myServletContext; // in case you need the servelet context

public server(ServletContext sc) {
       myServletContext = sc;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        // Create the server socket.
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Could not create server socket at 9090. Quitting.");
    }
    System.out.println("Listening for clients on 9090...");
    while (true) {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            try{
                DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                while (true) 
                   {
                    byte[] byteData = receiveData(is);
                    String frameData = new String(byteData).trim();
                    System.out.println("Incoming String's:-"+frameData);
                    new vtsDataDao().sendInputFrame(frameData);
                   }//end while
               }catch(Exception e){

               }//end ctry catch                
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out
                    .println("Exception encountered on accept. Ignoring. Stack Trace :");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> > ** Note:- in above class i am use two method 1. receiveData(DataInputStream is) for read i/p data and return VTS Data String And sendInputFrame(frameData);

web.XML

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>com.vts.action.MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```